# how to redirect on product detail page after search product by sku

Tags: magento2

Like I have a product with `sku: xra-ss1cr-600g15k` when I enter this id in search it redirect to this product detail instead of `catalogsearch` result filter page

Comment: Do you use ajax search?

Comment: I dont know about this I am new in magento